# update_attribute/s() is calling callback for save password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes, update-attribute

I'm trying to update single attribute of a user model from a admin controller (not users controller).

While doing this I tried `update_attribute()` but it was changing the users password also.

I think the password is changing because I have before_save method on user model which hashes the password.

`update_attributes()` is not working because it is checking the validations for password which is `presence=>true`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `update_column(name, value)`, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a condition on your validations by using the `:if` option. In my code, it looks something like this:

```
validates :password,
          :length => { :minimum => 8 },
          :confirmation => true,
          :presence => true,
          :if => :password_required?


def password_required?
  crypted_password.blank? || password.present?
end
```

So basically, it's only if the `crypted_password` in the database is not set (meaning a new record is being created) or if a new `password` is being provided that the validations are run.

Answer (score 0):

You can update single attribute of user like this

```
@user is that user whose attribute you want to update
```

e.g user_name

```
       @user.update_attributes(:user_name => "federe")
```

Try it and it will only update one attribute..

Comment: but it is checking for validations

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has an 'update-column' method that skips both validations **and** callbacks:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column

However, I'd suggest that could be dangerous - you have that :before_save filter for a reason. If you place an :except method on the filter to circumvent in specific cases, it not only becomes reusable but you keep behaviour consistent and avoid having a method buried in a controller that's bypassing your Model's validation/callback stack.

I'm personally not overly keen on seeing methods like update_column anywhere **except** as protected methods inside Models.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

To bypass callback and validations use :

```
User.update_all({:field_name => value},{:id => 1})
```

Just wanted to let you know :

- In Rails, update_attribute method bypasses model validations, while update_attributes and update_attributes! will fail (return false or raise an exception, respectively) if a record you are trying to save is not valid.
- The difference between two is update_attribute use save(false) where as update_attributes uses save or you can say save(true) .